# php strip tags except '<>' (book name)

Tags: php, strip-tags

How do I remove all the HTML tags in PHP, except the `<>` characters?

```
//There's other HTML tags, like h1, div, etc.
echo strip_tags('<gone with the wind> <p>a hotest book</p>');
```

This will return `a hotest book`, but I need to keep the book name. I need the function to return `<gone with the wind> a hotest book`.

Comment: Is this originally xml? If so, you shouldn't be parsing it as a string.

Comment: and how is PHP supposed to know what a book title looks like? `<50 shades of grey>` and `<the illiad>` both are valid (but unknown) html tags.

Comment: I guess defining a list of HTML tags and validating these as not part of the HTML lanuage in combination with the empty attributes would make this possible. But since you use < and > as identifiers this will be very resource expensive.

Comment: the code you're providing isn't valid HTML; `strip_tags()` expects to be given valid HTML. Whoever created this format really wasn't being clever -- it's going to be virtually impossible to parse it accurately. Go find the original author of this format, and give them a slap round the face with a wet fish.  ;-)

Comment: You mentioned a txt file in the comment section of an answer below. Please provide a chunk of about 5-6 books, so that we can see if there is a special pattern or something else that is being used to separate the entities.

Comment: Do the HTML tags only occur for the description component?. As @Daniel said, some more samples would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will utilize DOM to find any elements that are not valid HTML4 elements and consider them book titles. These will then be whitelisted in `strip_tags`.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

echo strip_tags($html, implode(',', 
    array_map(
        function($error) {
            return '<' . sscanf($error->message, 'Tag %s invalid')[0] . '>';
        },
        libxml_get_errors()
    )
));
```

[Online Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/00I3iL)

Take note that any book titles starting with a valid HTML tag will be considered valid HTML and thus stripped (for instance "Body of Evidence" or "Head First PHP"). Also note that `<gone with the wind>` is considered to be the element "gone" with attributes "with", "the" and "wind". For valid elements, you could check whether they have only empty attributes and then strip them if not, but that would still not be 100% accurate when the title consists of just the valid element name. In addition, you could check for closing tags, but I am not aware on how to do that with DOM (XMLParser can detect them though).

In any case, figuring out a better format for these book titles, e.g. using namespaces or using a different delimiter than angle brackets would greatly improve your chances to do this properly.

Comment: error report at line `return '<' . sscanf($error->message, 'Tag %s invalid')[0] . '>';`

Comment: @fishman if that line causes an error your PHP version does not support array dereferencing yet. Change it to `$book = sscanf($error->message, 'Tag %s invalid'); return '<'. $book[0] .'>';`

Answer (score 5):

You should consider using `&lt;` (<) and `&rt;` (>).

Comment: Yes, but a suggestion on how to do this would be useful.

Comment: You are not the one generating this data?

Comment: This should probably be the answer, if the coder has access to the data he wants to parse/read. I never thought about it and it might be useful to a lot of people.

Comment: @Manhim, these data not created by me, if use `htmlspecialchars($str,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8")`, this will change all the html tags.

Comment: Is the format standard? Like 1 entry per lines and the first tag is the title of the book?

Comment: @Manhim, Marc B, the original data is not created by me. they are stored in some txt files. may be i should use xpath dom parse to remove regular html tags?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple, although not foolproof solution for you.

**PHP**

```
$data = "<gone with the wind> <p>a hotest book</p>";
$out = preg_replace("/\<\w+\>|\<\/\w+\>/im", "", $data);

var_dump($out);
```

**Output**

```
string '<gone with the wind> a hotest book' (length=34)
```

**Would Match**

```
<p>text</p>
<anything>text</anything>
```

**Would Not Match**

Like one has said before, theres no way for the code to know what a Book Title looks like.

```
<img src="url">
```

Although, if you expect your data to be simple `<p>` tags, then this would work.

Crazy solution, thought I'd throw it out there.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it like that easier.

```
   <?php
   $string = htmlspecialchars("<gone with the wind>");
   echo strip_tags( "$string <p>a hotest book</p>");
   ?>
```

this wil out put :

```
   <gone with the wind> a hotest book
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hEBlUK)

Comment: what does `htmlspecialchars()` do?

Comment: `Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings.` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: the second parameter is for allowing the `<p>` tag, so this will remove everything but the `<p>` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '<gone with the wind> <p>a hotest book</p>';
$string = strip_tags(preg_replace("/<([\w\s\d]{6,})>/", "&lt;$1&gt;", $string));
$string = html_entity_decode($string);
```

The above will convert any 'tags' with more than six letters between `<>` to `&lt;&gt;` allowing you to then use strip_tags.

You may need to experiment with the six value depending on your incoming data. If you get a tag like `<article>` you may need to push it higher.

Comment: This will break a lot of valid HTML tags --  `<address>`, `<acronym>`, `<blockquote>`, `<colgroup>`.

Comment: @SDC Hence see the comment regarding experimenting with the value.

Comment: This will not work since book titles can be 1 or more characters long.

Comment: Also, what happens if someone actually writes a book with the title "Address" (or any of the other valid HTML tags)? the data format is broken; there's nothing you can do about it. It's fundamentally impossible to parse it accurately.

Comment: @Daniel Theoretically, yes. May work depending on the data set.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I could think of is to do something like this, since I didn't know what types of tags would be used I just assumed all of them, and this should remove any valid html tag not just ones that look like they could be tags.

```
<?php
$tags = array("!DOCTYPE","a","abbr","acronym","address","applet","area","article","aside","audio","b","base","basefont","bdi","bdo","big","blockquote","body","br","button","canvas","caption","center","cite","code","col","colgroup","command","datalist","dd","del","details","dfn","dir","div","dl","dt","em","embed","fieldset","figcaption","figure","font","footer","form","frame","frameset","h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6","head","header","hgroup","hr","html","i","iframe","img","input","ins","kbd","keygen","label","legend","li","link","map","mark","menu","meta","meter","nav","noframes","noscript","object","ol","optgroup","option","output","p","param","pre","progress","q","rp","rt","ruby","s","samp","script","section","select","small","source","span","strike","strong","style","sub","summary","sup","table","tbody","td","textarea","tfoot","th","thead","time","title","tr","track","tt","u","ul","var","video","wbr");

$string = "<gone with the wind> <p>a hotest book</p>";


echo preg_replace("/<(\/|)(".implode("|", $tags).").*>/iU", "", $string);
```

The final output looks like this:

```
<gone with the wind> a hotest book
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to be out of luck on this because you have no way of knowing which things in `<>` are HTML tags and which are the book title.  You can't even write something that looks for things that look like tags but aren't actually valid HTML tags, since you might get a record for the Monkees' 1968 movie "Head", which would come across as `<Head>` which certainly is a valid HTML tag.

You'll need to work this out with the supplier of your data, and then you can use the PHP `strip_tags` function.